# Angularjs filter limit to include two params

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want to use it just as limitTo(input,begin,end)?
How to set the begin index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On Version 1.4**

As highlighted by **@doldt** Angular 1.4 now added the feature to indicate the begin of and end of in the limit:

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/filter/limitTo

**Previous version 1.4**
Angular `limitTo` does not support more than one argument:

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit}}
```

The filter `limitTo` creates a new array or string containing only the specified number of elements in the `limit` argument.

Therefore the recommended option is to create a custom filter.

For example here is an **[Online Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mscRMAzIkykJYOh6Hs8K?p=preview)** and this is how you can do it:

Please note that the first argument of the filter is the "Data Source" ( the entire list). It is the purpose of the filter to filter the Data Source.

HTML Sample

```
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="row in friends |myFilter:2:5 ">{{row.name}}</li>
<ul>
```

Js App and filter creation

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(items, begin, end) {                                     

            return items.slice( begin, end);
        }
    });

function myCtrl($scope)
{    
    $scope.friends = [
      {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
    ];
}

myApp.controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);
```

Comment: Update: as of angular 1.4.0 limitTo accepts a second argument to be used as begin index.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own filter to achieve this. Try below,

```
app.filter('limitFromTo', function(){
    return function(input, from, to){
        return (input != undefined)? input.slice(from, to) : '';
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitFromTo : from : to}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achive the disired result by sequential application of `limitTo` filter to the array.
Say you want to extract items from 4 to 9:

**HTML:**

```
{{ someArray | limitTo: to | limitTo: from}}
```

**JS**

```
var from = 4;
$scope.to = 9;
$scope.from = from - $scope.to; // This value must be a negative
```